# Get sound working with startx

Tags: sound, 14.10, i3-wm

I have set up my computer to boot to a text environment and then I enter

> startx

to start an i3 session

When I do this my sound does not work alsamixer does not work. But if I do

> sudo start lightdm

Then the sound and alsamixer works.

How do I get the sound to work when I run startx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have to add your user to audio group**

`sudo adduser <username> audio`

*Replace `<username>` with your actual username*

**Restart your PC to take effect**